# Prove the reflexivity of $\subseteq$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

My professor gave me a list of exercises, I've been able to figure out what mechanism I should exploit to prove them, but I'd like to know if it's good. Until now we've been taught a little logic and he introduced some axioms of set theory. The question may be utterly trivial, but I've made some work and wanna know if my reasoning is correct.

From what I have, my guess is that I should employ some of the given axioms and definitions, then for proving $A\subseteq A$, I guess I should get the definition:

$$A\subseteq B \iff \forall x, (x\in A \implies x \in B)$$

And apply it to my case:

$$A\subseteq A \iff \forall x, (x\in A \implies x \in A)$$

And from the truth table of $\implies$:

$$\begin{matrix}
{A}&{B}&{(A \implies B)}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{1}\\ 
{0}&{1}&{1}\\
{1}&{0}&{0}\\  
{1}&{1}&{1}
\end{matrix}$$

In my case:

$$\begin{matrix}
{A}&{A}&{(A \implies A)}\\ 
{0}&{0}&{1}\\  
{1}&{1}&{1}
\end{matrix}$$

I believe it's proved with this. Is it okay?

Comment: I don't like it because $\forall x(x\in A\implies x\in B)$ isn't a conditional statement. The universal quantifier has a larger scope than $\implies$. I'd prefer to write something like "Take an arbitrary $x$". Now you can do what you did to the statement $x\in A\implies x\in A$. Once you've fixed an $x$, you get rid of the universal quantifier.

Comment: @GitGud Excuse me. But what's the difference of $\forall$ and "take an arbitrary $x$"?

Comment: Truth tables are for statements in propositional calculus (not exactly, but let's simply things). How are you going to construct a  truth table for $\forall xP(x)$? **Edit:** Once you fix $x$, you can deal with $x\in A\implies x\in A$ and now you can use valuations.

Comment: @GitGud I don't really know. I've imagined some things but none of them is nice. I remember of the "getting hid of $\forall x$", I've heard a small piece about it in a lecture but I had to leave and didn't get the rest.

Comment: What I really should be focusing is on the fact that $\forall x(x\in A\implies x\in A)$ isn't a statement of neither of this forms: $P\lor Q, P\land Q, P\implies Q$. Only by eliminating the universal quantifier, does it become one of these.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, but what you mean with "eliminating the universal quantifier"? Is there a process to do it or I just need to throw it away?

Comment: Informally it corresponds to the "Take an arbitrary $x$".

Comment: @GitGud: I don't understand your objection. Is it just about notation?

Comment: @KyleGannon No. I will be merely reiterating what I just said. I object against using truth tables for a statement which doesn't look like one of these: $P\lor Q, P\land Q, P\implies Q$. First it should be transformed in one of these.

Comment: The down vote to the question baffles me.

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed right.  Git Gud's objection doesn't really apply if the definition you learned for $\subseteq$ is the one you wrote, because it seems that's how your teacher writes down such things.

Comment: The definition is the one he wrote, there is no other. My objection still applies.

Comment: Of course the definition is _conceptually_ that.  What I mean is, if the _notation_ used by teacher to give the definition is $\forall x, (x\in A \Leftrightarrow x\in B}$, one can hardly complain that the student is using the same notation.  And the truth table complaint strikes me as a bit pedantic too. (I give the student the benefit of the doubt that  he's using $A$ and $B$ in column headers as shorthand for $x\in A$ and $x\in B$.)

Comment: If I understood correctly you think I have a problem with the comma. I don't like the comma, but I don't have a problem with it.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the comma (though I wouldn't use it myself).  In truth I don't have a problem with the solution at all, and tried to convey that in my answer.  When I wrote my answer, you only had one comment, and it seemed like your objection was to the use of the universal quantifier.  I realize now that I didn't sufficiently understand your objection (and possibly still don't) so I shouldn't have mentioned it in my answer.  If you prefer I can rephrase my answer so as not to involve you.

Answer (score 1):

i can not approve the Git Gud's objection either.
since (for any x (true)) is true, and in our case "((x from A) -> (x from A))" variable x is no longer significant by the definition of implication.

so that the applicant did not use the truth table for the formula (for any x P(x)) -- he indeed showed that P(x) in the formula does not depend on x.

am i wrong?